# awk else statement not working converting bytes in column to mb and gb and tb

Tags: awk

Trying to reformat bytes in column to mb and gb based on if else.

In my data last column is size in bytes. Wanting to convert bytes to mb and gb. if less than 1gb (1073741824 bytes) convert to mb and append MB, if equal to or greater than 1gb than convert to gb and append GB

```
awk -F ',' '{if ($NF >= "1073741824") {$NF=$NF/1024/1024/1024; gsub(/.*/, "&GB", $NF)} else { $NF=$NF/1024/1024; gsub(/.*/, "&MB", $NF)}}1'
```

But else statement is not working. If bytes are greater than or equal to 1gb convert it to gb else to mb.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add concise, testable sample input and expected output that demonstrates your problem. Also "is not working" is famously the worst possible problem statement. In any situation in life where you need help with anything (at a doctor's office, at a car mechanic, on a software forum, etc.), never just say "it's not working", always provide details about in what way it's not working so people can best help you, in this case tell us if it's wrong output, no output, error messages, something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One general issue is with the conditional; the current code is performing a string comparison when it should be performing a numeric comparison.

Consider:

```
# string comparison ($1 >= "300")

$ echo 100000 | awk '{if ($1 >= "300") print "greater than 300"}'
    - returns nothing

# numeric comparison ($1 >= 300)

$ echo 100000 | awk '{if ($1 >= 300) print "greater than 300"}'
greater than 300
```

Rolling this into OP's code (remove double quotes from around the `1073741824`:

```
# old:
awk -F ',' '{if ($NF >= "1073741824") {$NF=$NF/1024/1024/1024; gsub(/.*/, "&GB", $NF)} else { $NF=$NF/1024/1024; gsub(/.*/, "&MB", $NF)}}1'
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^

# new:
awk -F ',' '{if ($NF >=  1073741824 ) {$NF=$NF/1024/1024/1024; gsub(/.*/, "&GB", $NF)} else { $NF=$NF/1024/1024; gsub(/.*/, "&MB", $NF)}}1'
                         ^^^^^^^^^^
```

If this edit of the current code does not address the issue then please update the question with the updated code, sample input, (wrong) output generated by the code and the (correct) expected output.

Comment: For the OPs benefit - you could also write that code as `awk -F ',' 'BEGIN{k=1024; m=k^2; g=k^3} {$NF=($NF >=  g ? ($NF / g) "GB" : ($NF / m) "MB")}1'` for less redundancy and better efficiency.